# OpenGL - VBOs for 2D Rendering theoretical animation issues

Tags: opengl, animation, shader, textures, vbo

So lately I decided to create a game and use the new versions of OpenGL to accomplish it (Note: the game is 2D).

So far I have a VBO for each class that is draw-able. I did this to avoid having a VBO for 1 instance of a class (6*3 elements). Now as you know **before** you render VBOs you bind texture. Now the problem is that I started to implement Animation then I realized that Animation is **not** possible this way, I cannot render a VBO that may contain 5 turtles with different texture for each turtle (different texture for each animation keyframe).

**So to recap this is the problem:** * One VBO holds multiple turtles. One turtle decides to attack. Start animation by switching to attack texture. Render. All turtles in the VBO are attacking.*

**Now this is the question:**

- Is there a way to switch texture inside the shaders?
- if the above is not possible what can I do?

Comment: "*One VBO holds multiple turtles*" Has it occurred to you that maybe *that's* your problem? 2D games, generally speaking, have rather ephemeral mesh data. You're going to have to change your vertex data frequently, so you should just accept that. This means every object needs its own vertex data.

Comment: So what are you saying? Use One VBO for One turtle?

Comment: How many buffer objects you have is completely irrelevant. What you need to do is stop having each turtle use the same *vertex data*, as though each turtle was a clone of the other. They can share storage for their vertex data, but they can't share the actual vertices themselves.

Comment: They don't. All they share is the same FloatBuffer and the same textureID

Comment: The VBO holds 6*3 elements for EACH turtle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my own solution:

For each object that can have animation, make a spritesheet then only change the ST coords instead of rebinding the texture for the next frame.

Comment: I heard about it but I felt spritesheets accomplish the job just as well, and without a limit on how many frames.. (So pretty much they are better and easier to deal with)